# Rocksdb deleted records are visible in iterator

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

Below is my pseudocode.

```
1. Begin transaction
2. Create iterator
3. Delete first record from iterator and move next on iterator
4. commit transaction
5. If there's end of iterator then create new iterator and repeat from step #1
```

Note: Iterator range include all records. We are passing correct upper slice and lower slice.

After Step#5 iterator returns even deleted records.

Rocksdb Version: 6.29.5

Can someone please help?

Comment: Share the real code - there is probably a bug in your code

Comment: since the iterator was created before the record was deleted it still sees it